# ListView, ArrayAdapter in Android

Tags: java, android

I need some help with my class

1. I have to make an asynchronous call to the method `getTodaysTweets()`
   in `TweetUtil` to retrieve data.
2. POPULAR list of data you collected.
3. View dialog for the app work while the asynchronous call of
   `TweetUtil` is in progress.

**Class**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity{
private ListView listOfTweets;
private ArrayAdapter<String> tweetsAdapter;

protected void onCreate (Bundle savedInstanceState){
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

listOfTweets = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listOfTweets);
tweetsAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1);
listOfTweets.setAdapter(tweetsAdapter);

//To:DO Get list of tweets from TweetUtil and populate list
//Do this asynchronus

}
}

public class TweetUtil{
public static List<String> getTodaysTweets(){
List<String> tweets = new ArrayList<String>();
//...getting tweets from twitter.com
//...adding the result to my List<String> tweets

return tweets;
}
}
```

Comment: using AsyncTask class that's will save your day and below good tutorial for it

http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidBackgroundProcessing/article.html

Comment: AsyncTask class help you to make asynchronous  calling from Database or remote server and it's manage all threads you work , so you can call your method in your custom AsyncTask class

Comment: you are welcome  , you could make this comment useful for others

Comment: hmm but how can i do that ? there is no  option for giving any point to the comment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

using `AsyncTask` class that's will save your day and below good tutorial for it .
AsyncTask class help you to make asynchronous calling from Database or remote server and it's manage all threads you work , so you can call your method in your custom `AsyncTask` class –

good source for it :

http://vogella.com/articles/AndroidBackgroundProcessing/article.html